# Dev Express validation message not showing within .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, devexpress-mvc

I am working with a legacy .NET application that uses a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` control. I have full source code access to a .NET MVC web application that is exposed through this WebBrowser control. Of course, the MVC web app is also available via a normal web browser (in my case, IE 11).

The MVC app uses DevExpress 15.1.5 for many of it's UI components, and I am having some issues with rendering/behavior differences between the WebBrowser control rendered "version" and the IE 11 "version" of the application. The main issue I'd like to resolve is that dev express validation messages do not appear in the WebBrowser rendering, but they do appear in the IE 11 rendering. Here is an example:

```
 <td class="">
  @Html.DevExpress().SpinEditFor(x => x.SomeRange,
    settings => {
    settings.Name = "SomeRange";
    settings.Properties.MinValue = 0;
    settings.Properties.MaxValue = 100;
        settings.Properties.NullText = "Some Range";
    settings.Properties.NumberType = SpinEditNumberType.Integer;
 }).GetHtml()
</td>
```

When a user enters a value greater than 100, in the IE 11 rendering, they are presented with an validation message that says:

> The number must be in the range 0...100

However, when a user performs this in the WebBrowser control version, no message is displayed.

The WebBrowser is, with certainty, rendering with IE 11 document mode. I have verified this by forcing it to do so via the [registry settings mentioned here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version), and checking the `document.documentMode` in both WebBrowser and IE 11 to verify they are both the same (and they were, both return `11`).

```
Legacy App (WebBrowser Control)
appName:        Netscape
appVersion:     5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
documentMode:   11 

IE 11
appName:        Netscape
appVersion:     5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko
documentMode:   11
```

Notably, there are some other *slight* rendering differences between the two, for example I noticed that default no-css `<button>` elements are styled slightly differently (a WebBrowser `<button>` looked like it may have been from IE 7).

I'm not so worried about the rendering differences (I only notice differences on default un-styled controls) but I do need the validation messages to appear. Any idea on what to check next, or how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi, test your WBC control by loading the content/website in IE, then use the dev tool to inspect elements and determine which IE Emulation mode suites your WBC application. eg... it might use Shockwave flash (Not Adobe's flash) which require IE emulation, or changing your html source code on your web site.
WBC applications by default assume IE7 emulation by default, however you should code your html to html5 (if possible) and set the feature_control_emulation to IE=11.000 see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RobParsons- this was actually the first thing I tried. I set `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to 11001 for the WBC app, as the MVC app works as expected in IE11 with Document Mode set to "Edge". Note that the `http-equiv` tag in the MVC app is set to:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

 I also tested with other settings for `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, going all the way back down to 7000 (IE7 emulation) which started to break, and also broke in IE 11 with it's emulation mode set to IE7, as we don't support this app for older browsers.